# Open / Import a DBF file into MSAccess 2003

Tags: database, ms-access, import

How can I open or import a dbf file into MS Access 2003? I know I can do it with Access07, but I can't use it now...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Get External Data > Import...
Then change the 'Files of type' to 'dBASE 5', 'dBASE III' or 'dBASE IV'